# Views Data Export: How can you include a raw database column?

Tags: views, database, comments, importing-exporting

I'm running a data export (using Views Data Export) on some comments and I'd like to include the `thread` column in the result. The only thing I can see is a `Depth` field, which doesn't contain the detailed thread information needed to re-render the comments in the correct order. Is it possible to include the `thread` database column in the results?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Table column will not be automatically imported as available views field. Any extra field you want to use in views. You can define it with [`hook_views_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7.x-3.x). Anyway, I can find pretty much fields are ready to use.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to import the `thread` column from the `comment` table. This column isn't shown in views. There is a `Depth` option, but it doesn't export the same data that's stored in the `thread` column (which is used to order threaded comments in the correct order).

Comment: @DanMurfitt How about using the hook?

Comment: I could - but I'd have to build a module. I was wondering if there were any ways to do this using existing modules?

Comment: Or can you explain what kind of order you want?

Comment: If you see this Drupal article it will explain why you need this data when displaying threaded comments https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_get_thread/7.x

Comment: @DanMurfitt um... I know this... dot `.` is used to determine the depth of thread and the number is determine the post order... What I am thinking is that you can use post date as order and pid (ID of parent comment) as group to make that.

Comment: Good idea, but I think the depth would stop working when the thread goes to more than 1 level deep because the `thread` column not only stores the order, but it also stores the depth (for comments that are replies to replies to replies etc.)

Comment: Um... I don't think views can handle this kind of multi-layer hierarchical structure....

Comment: It can't (to my knowledge, anyway), but I only need to export the raw database field along with each comment when doing a views export :)